# Ubuntu V14.04 login problem?

Tags: 14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 operating system. I have login problem now, when I enter my password for login to reach out at desktop of my operating system. it reload same window to enter your password. When I put wrong password it show me error "invalid password try again", but when I enter correct password it comes on same window for enter your password instead of desktop work area. And when I try to login as a guest session it appears same window again for enter your password. Please give me some suggestions to come out of this and able to work with my Ubuntu system.

---

When I perform Ctrl+alt+F2 and login my system its shows me :-

```
welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-33-generic i686) *Documentation: HTTPS://help.Ubuntu.com/
23 package can be updated.
0 updates are security updates. -bash: groups: command not found. Command 'ls' is available is '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found.
Command 'lesspipe' is available in the following places.
*/bin/lesspipe.
*/usr/bin/lesspipe.
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
Lesspipe: command not found
Command 'dircolors' is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'.
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
dircolors: command not found.
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls' 
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32046/room-for-terdon-and-akydev), you made changed to `/etc/environment` which broke your PATH. As a consequence, your login manager couldn't find the executables it needed to run in order to log you in. To fix this, edit your `/etc/environment` file set the correct `$PATH`:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in from the command line.
2. Run this command to edit the file:

   /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nano /etc/environment
3. Delete anything in that file and replace it with the line below. Make sure there is nothing in the file except this line:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
   ```
4. Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>
5. Return to the GUI login manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and try to log in again. It should work as expected.

Comment: Ok as you told I try to run but I don't have much knowledge about it. Cmd 1: sudo /bin/rm~/.Xauthority . cmd 2 : sudo /bin/mv "$i" "$i" old ??  Cmd 3: sudo /bin/cp /etc/skel/"$i"~/ ?? I don't understand the cmd 2 and cmd 3 please tell me how to perform.

Comment: @Akydev just copy/paste everything directly into the terminal if you can. The `for i in ...; done` is one command, not many. Come join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32046/room-for-terdon-and-akydev) where we can discuss it more easily.

Comment: Terdon I texted you at Chat room.

Comment: I like to Thank you very much . if any one need any help i guess #Terdon is nice helping guy ;)

Answer (score -1):

You could try this in sted:

```
 sudo dkms-reconfigure Xauthority
```

and it might work fine this way

Comment: I can't able to perform sudo dkms-reconfigure Xauthority . it shows that : command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo' . the command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable. Sudo : command not found.

Comment: install dkms type this in sudo apt-get install dkms